Why autocompletion with tab does not show name of the lauch files in a ros 2 python bringup package?
ROS 2 Humble, Ubuntu 22.04, x86_64 CPU
Hello,
In a ROS 2 workspace I created a package called my_launcher whose directory tree looks like the following

my_launcher

launch

paper2.py


CmakeLists.txt
package.xml
pyproject.toml [for ruff linting]
setup.py



I can build the package okay and can run the launch file using ros2 launch my_launcher paper2.py
However, after typing in ros2 launch my_launcher if I press tab the following is shown

Why auto completion is unable to find paper2.py launch file?
Is setup.py even needed for a ros2 bringup package?
I tried removing the setup.py but it did not solve this issue.
My CmakeLists.txt looks like the following
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_launcher)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclpy)

# This command will "install" the launch file. Will allow ros2.launch find this package from the terminal
install(DIRECTORY launch DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}) 

ament_package()


And the setup.py as follows
from setuptools import setup
import os
from glob import glob

package_name = 'my_launcher'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages', ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'launch'), ['launch/paper2.py']),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'config'), ['config/my_config_file.yaml']),  # if you have config files
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='Azmyin M Kamal',
    maintainer_email='akamal4@lsu.edu',
    description='Launchers the two Neural network python nodes',
    license='License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
        ],
    },
)


launch autocompletion will look for Python files ending with .launch.py or _launch.py. Your launch file does not match hence you have to type it manually. I would suggest renaming it to paper2_launch.py

Thank you, I will try it and get back to you. Is there a reference to this rule? I don't recall seeing this here

Renaming to paper2_launch.py solved this problem. Thanks.
